# DateTimePicker not displaying the right date

Tags: swift, xcode, datetimepicker

I'm using a DateTimePicker that contains a Start Date and Time. Although the time updates properly, the date does not update based on the scrollview. Any idea what I can change to make it work?

Here's the code:

```
class DateTimePicker: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
  // Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878547/is-it-possible-to-have-uidatepicker-work-with-start-and-end-time
    
    var didSelectDates: ((_ start: Date) -> Void)?
      
      private lazy var pickerView: UIPickerView = {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.backgroundColor = .white
        return pickerView
      }()
      
      private var days = [Date]()
      private var startTimes = [Date]()
//      private var endTimes = [Date]()
      
      let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
      let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
      
      var inputView: UIView {
        return pickerView
      }
      
      func setup() {
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = "EE d MMM"
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        days = setDays()
        startTimes = setStartTimes()
//        endTimes = setEndTimes()
      }
      
      // MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate & DateSource
      
      func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
      }
      
      func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch component {
        case 0:
          return days.count
        case 1:
          return startTimes.count
//        case 2:
//          return endTimes.count
        default:
          return 0
        }
      }
      
      func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var label: UILabel
        
        if let view = view as? UILabel {
          label = view
        } else {
          label = UILabel()
        }
        
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        
        var text = ""
        
        switch component {
        case 0:
          text = getDayString(from: days[row])
        case 1:
          text = getTimeString(from: startTimes[row])
//        case 2:
//          text = getTimeString(from: endTimes[row])
        default:
          break
        }
        
        label.text = text
        
        return label
      }
      
      func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        let dayIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let startTimeIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
//        let endTimeIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
        
        guard days.indices.contains(dayIndex),
                startTimes.indices.contains(startTimeIndex)
//                endTimes.indices.contains(endTimeIndex)
          else { return }

        let startTime = startTimes[startTimeIndex]
//        let endTime = endTimes[endTimeIndex]
        
        didSelectDates?(startTime)
      }
      
      // MARK: - Private helpers
      
      private func getDays(of date: Date) -> [Date] {
        var dates = [Date]()
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        // first date
        var currentDate = date
        
        // adding 30 days to current date
        let oneMonthFromNow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: currentDate)
        
        // last date
        let endDate = oneMonthFromNow
        
        while currentDate <= endDate! {
          dates.append(currentDate)
          currentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        }
        
        return dates
      }
      
      private func getTimes(of date: Date) -> [Date] {
        var times = [Date]()
        var currentDate = date
        
        currentDate = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 7, of: currentDate)!
        currentDate = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .minute, value: 00, of: currentDate)!
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let interval = 60
        var nextDiff = interval - calendar.component(.minute, from: currentDate) % interval
        var nextDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: nextDiff, to: currentDate) ?? Date()
        
        var hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: nextDate)
        
        while(hour < 23) {
          times.append(nextDate)
          
          nextDiff = interval - calendar.component(.minute, from: nextDate) % interval
          nextDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: nextDiff, to: nextDate) ?? Date()
          
          hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: nextDate)
        }
        
        return times
      }
      
      private func setDays() -> [Date] {
        let today = Date()
        return getDays(of: today)
      }
      
      private func setStartTimes() -> [Date] {
        let today = Date()
        return getTimes(of: today)
      }
      
//      private func setEndTimes() -> [Date] {
//        let today = Date()
//        return getTimes(of: today)
//      }
      
      private func getDayString(from: Date) -> String {
        return dayFormatter.string(from: from)
      }
      
      private func getTimeString(from: Date) -> String {
        return timeFormatter.string(from: from)
      }
      
    }

    extension Date {

      static func buildTimeRangeString(startDate: Date) -> String {
        
        let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d"

        let startTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        startTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h a"
        
//        let endTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
//        endTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        
        return String(format: "%@, %@",
                      dayFormatter.string(from: startDate),
                      startTimeFormatter.string(from: startDate))
//                      endTimeFormatter.string(from: endDate))
      }
    }
```

(Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZsJwsZ3iKQ)

In the main MessagesViewController, I have :

```
    private lazy var dateTimePicker: DateTimePicker = {
        let picker = DateTimePicker()
        picker.setup()
        picker.didSelectDates = {[weak self](startDate) in
            let text = Date.buildTimeRangeString(startDate: startDate)
            self?.actualDate = startDate
            self?.label.text = text
            dateText = text
        }
        return picker
    }()
```

Comment: UIKit contains a native `UIDatePicker` component that should do what you are trying to do "out of the box". Why not use that?

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't using the built-in `UIDatePicker` view?

Comment: I wanted to implement a scroll type view with simplified dates and times. (I'm also fairly new to Swift). How should I go about implementing that?

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://iamyash.com/index.php/tag/date-picker-swift-5-programmatically/

Comment: I think I'd prefer use the custom date picker because it only has times every hour, as opposed to minutes with the UIDatePicker which is harder to customize. Any issues you can identify with the code I provided?

Comment: Anyone have ideas?